# How to get notifications for access requests in SharePoint Online / Office 365?

Tags: sharepoint-online, access-denied

I'm a co-owner of a SharePoint site hosted on Office 365 (`*.sharepoint.com`). I used to get notifications whenever a user got an "Access denied" page and they requested access. The notification was an email showing me their reason for access, and I could click a link in that email to approve/decline their request.

Recently I stopped receiving those notifications, so people would have to manually send me an email telling me to go look for their access request and approve it. I did not turn off notifications explicitly (I have no idea how to do that).

I went to the "gear" icon, clicked `Site Settings`, and there's an `Access requests and invitations`, and that shows the list of people requesting access. But I don't see any option there to get email notifications.

How do I enable email notifications for access requests to my SharePoint site?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Open Site Settings -> Then Click on Site Permissions -> From Ribbon (Permission Tab) Click on Access Request Settings.

This will open up a dialog window where you can specify the email address.

Comment: Thanks! Interestingly, that does seem to be set up correctly - but nevertheless it's not working. It's set up to send email to an email DL (set up through Forefront Identity Manager) but I'm not getting the emails. I'll open another question on how to find out why this isn't working.

Comment: Here's my follow-up question for reference: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/120486/email-notifications-from-sharepoint-online-for-access-requests-dont-seem-to-be

Comment: Can you set this to the current site owner? Just so that I don't have to specify an e-mail address.

Comment: You can set everyone in the site owner's group to receive access requests. Just make sure the Site Owners radio button is selected instead of the e-mail address radio button