# Access request e-mails to get sent to the site owner, not a static e-mail address

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, access, requestaccessmail

I have learned how to [set-up access requests](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/120477/how-to-get-notifications-for-access-requests-in-sharepoint-online-office-365) within SharePoint 2013, however I'd like for this to not be a static e-mail address, **is there a way to set the access requests to go to the "site owner" instead of a static e-mail address?**

I'm asking because, let's say we've decided that the site-owner should be the person to approve/reject requests, but what if that person changes, what if they go on holiday and set the site-owner to the 2IC in the interim?

Answer (score 3):

I dont think you can have a dynamic change of site owner email address in OOTB. you may use below workarounds,

1. You may use a group mail box id instead of assigning the access
   request to a single user. Whenever a new user is assigned as Site
   owner, you may configure the user to access the Group mail box.
2. Else, go for customization. Create a list named 'Site Owner' while
   adding a new site owner use an event reciever and update the access
   request email id.
3. Else use sharepoint designer workflow with REST api call within APP
   step and update the access request email id

Comment: Interesting points. I don't like the idea of manually having to change a site owner or a mail group (and It's not safe to leave it up to the users); however your second two points are worth digging into. Thank you.

Comment: Mark it as answer, if it had helped you.